# Is Elasicsearch's synonym resolution recursive?

Tags: elasticsearch

As we build our synonyms configuration in Solr format, does Lucene perform recursive query replacement?

For example, if one specifies:

```
meat => beef, pork, poultry
beef => steak, hamburger, filet
pork => hot dog, ham, bacon
poultry => chicken, hen, turkey
```

Will a query for "meat" resolve to querying for all of the specific replacements, in this case, steak, hamburger, filet, hot dog, ham, bacon, chicken, hen, and turkey? Or will Lucene just search for beef, pork, and poultry?

Answer (score 1):

No, the synonyms are not applied recursively. In your example, meat will only be replaced by beef, pork, poultry, and no further replacements.